# Azure PostgreSQL as a Service Latency Issues

Tags: postgresql, azure, latency, paas

We're experiencing latency issues when querying Azure managed PostgreSQL. Basically a normal query takes a minimum of 0.5s to 0.8s to return a response. Even an empty select query takes that long. When using incorrect credentials the response time drops to 0.01s. Maybe an authentication issue behind the scenes?

My colleagues have tried using a VM in the same data center and that hasn't helped. We've even tried creating an instance with more CPU power and that hasn't helped.

Other than provisioning a VM and installing PostgreSQL on the VM, can anyone suggest how to decrease this latency in the Azure managed database?

Comment: Same issue here with an open ticket MS side. keep in touch.

Comment: Same here, see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/68917e89-74d3-4d04-ba74-1554401286d5/very-high-latency-with-azure-database-for-postgres?forum=AzureDatabaseforPostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

I'm using azures managed postgres. In the beginning we were experiencing queries taking long like you describe (especially the first query for a request).

Our problem was a connection setting to not keep the connections open. Setting a long timeout would fix the problem partly and we'd only see the extra time added whenever a connection reached the timeout.

Now we've added pgbouncer to pool connections so we never have any of the connection overhead.

If you're still having this problem try to troubleshoot and see how much overhead opening a connection is. For us it would usually be 100 - 1000 ms